# What is the correct usage of "cause"?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

Regarding the following construction

> Lengthy literature survey is mainly *caused for* this extension.

I would like to ask:

1. Do I correctly use "cause" in above sentence?
2. What is the general rule when using "cause"?

Comment: I think you are using "caused for" where you should use "due to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 No - your current sentence is ungrammatical. You probably should use *because* instead of *cause*

> The main reason I need an extension is **because** the literature survey took so long.

If you want to keep the word cause, you can use the slightly more stilted

> The lengthy literature survey **caused** me to need an extension.

2 Use of the word **cause** is given in the dictionary:

> **Cause** *Noun*
>
> A person or thing that gives rise to an action, phenomenon, or condition.
>
> *Verb*
>
> Make (something) happen: "this disease can cause blindness".

Comment: that mean, cause doesnt want to use with 'to'?

Comment: Another possibility, though more roundabout, is "The lengthy literature survey is the main cause for this extension."

Comment: @gnp: Not exactly. As a noun, **cause** behaves like the noun **reason**. So *the fire in my kitchen gave me cause to shout for help* is fine. As a verb, *cause* normally takes the form "X caused Y" or "X caused Y to Z" for example: *My toaster caused a fire to start in my kitchen*.

Comment: +1 for stating that noun cause behaves like reason. My book 'Oxford English Grammar' is also stating the exact same thing.